# SQL Server : inner joins and group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that counts the number of enquiries made by a phone operator per day

```
SELECT 
   [OperatorID],
   DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate,
   COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
FROM 
   [Enquiries] AS e
GROUP BY 
   [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0)
```

However, I want to add the `Operator` table to this query so that I can retrieve the operators name

```
SELECT [OperatorID]
  ,[FirstName]
  ,[LastName]
FROM [Operators]
```

If I inner join the 2 tables before the group by clause:

```
SELECT [OperatorID]
  , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
  , COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
  , st.FullName
FROM [Enquiries] AS e

INNER JOIN

(SELECT     OperatorID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName 
FROM          dbo.Operators
WHERE      (Role = 'Operator')) AS o ON e.OperatorID = o.OperatorID

GROUP BY [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0)
```

I get the following error:

> Column 'o.FullName' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `st.FullName` to the `Group by`:

```
GROUP BY 
   [OperatorID], 
   DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0), 
   st.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus. Amazingly quick response. Cheers

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it answered the question. Thanks to all the other suggestions though.

Answer (score 2):

As `OperatorID` is more distinctive than `FullName` than you can safely add `FullName` to group by clause:

```
SELECT [OperatorID]
  , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
  , COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
  , st.FullName
FROM [Enquiries] AS e

INNER JOIN

(SELECT     OperatorID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName 
FROM          dbo.Operators
WHERE      (Role = 'Operator')) AS o ON e.OperatorID = o.OperatorID

GROUP BY [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0), st.FullName
```

**UPDATE** As stated in comments, I'd recommend do the aggregation first by minimal required amount of columns, and then decorate results.

```
SELECT si.[OperatorID], si.CreationDate, si.EnquiryCount, st.FullName
FROM

(
    SELECT [OperatorID]
      , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
      , COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
    FROM [Enquiries]
    GROUP BY [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0)
) AS si

INNER JOIN

(
    SELECT     OperatorID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName 
    FROM          dbo.Operators
    WHERE      (Role = 'Operator')
) AS st

   ON si.OperatorID = st.OperatorID
```

Actually I am not sure, why you need to subquery `Operators`. If it is not necessary then the solution can be simplified:

```
SELECT si.[OperatorID], si.CreationDate, si.EnquiryCount,
    st.FirstName + ' ' + st.LastName AS FullName
FROM

(
    SELECT [OperatorID]
      , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
      , COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
    FROM [Enquiries]
    GROUP BY [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0)
) AS si

INNER JOIN

Operators AS st
  ON si.OperatorID = st.OperatorID and st.Role = 'Operator'
```

Comment: and for the long run I'd recommend adding FullName as a join to the already aggregated data, as grouping over OperatorID is much faster then grouping over OperatorID + FullName. if you are interested - let  me know.

Comment: Thanks Kuba, Yes, I'd like to see an example of what you mean.

Comment: Thanks kuba for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Please try, I have not tested! hoping this will solve the error

`SELECT [OperatorID], CONCAT(FirstName,LastName) AS FullName 
  , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
  , COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount
  , st.FullName
FROM [Enquiries] AS e
INNER JOIN dbo.Operators ON dbo.Operators.OperatorID = e.OperatorID AND (Role = 'Operator')
GROUP BY [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression with `ROW_NUMBER` function and `COUNT(*)OVER`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT e.[OperatorID]
  , DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, e.CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate
  , o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS FullName 
  , RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [o.OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, e.CreationDate), 0) ORDER BY e.CreationDate DESC)
  , EnquiryCount = COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY [o.OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, e.CreationDate), 0))
   FROM [Enquiries] AS e
   INNER JOIN  dbo.Operators o ON e.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
   WHERE Role = 'Operator'
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a common table expression you can do

```
with cte as (
SELECT  
   [OperatorID], 
   DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) AS CreationDate, 
   COUNT(*) AS EnquiryCount 
FROM  
   [Enquiries] AS e 
GROUP BY  
   [OperatorID], DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, CreationDate), 0) 
)
SELECT
 cte.OperatorI,cte.CreationDate,o.FirstName + ' ' + o.LastName AS FullName   
FROM
 cte inner join dbo.Operators o
 on o.Role = 'Operator' and e.OperatorID = o.OperatorID
```